# Website responsivo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Alguém me pode ajudar a colocar no site que estou a desenvolver ao que dizem de ser *responsive*, ou seja, quando acedo através de um smarthphone o website ajusta-se ao smartphone e se minimizar a janela do browser no desktop/laptop o website ajustar-se a ele?

O que eu vi foi estilo isso: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Mas queria para o meu site e não estou a conseguir colocar, o site ajusta-se ao tamanho da janela em que esta a ser visualizado.

Cumprimentos e Obrigado

Comment: Um framework que eu aconselho é o Bootstrap. É bem produtivo. Mais informações em: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Aqui está jovem padawam: [Tabela de comparação entre frameworks CSS](http://usablica.github.io/front-end-frameworks/compare.html). Estudar você deve.

Comment: Deixar um site responsivo caberia em um livro o nível de explicação, o que não é o objetivo deste site.

Comment: Procura sobre Media queries, assim você consegue ajustar o layout de acordo com a resolução que deseja, e com várias media queries de acordo com cada ponto de quebra do código. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries

Answer (score 1):

Deixar um site responsivo não é como adicionar uma feature no seu site, para isso é necessário um prática de estilização específica para isso, coisas que vão de um bom uso de unidades de medida (%, em, px, vw, etc) até um bom uso de breckpoints. É fundamental ter um conhecimento pelo menos intermediário de css para deixar um site realmente responsivo.

Uma coisa que pode ajudar muito a sua vida é o uso de bibliotecas de CSS, a mais usada e que é de muito fácil uso é o bootstrap, ele possui um sistema de grid que facilitara muito o processo de deixar um site responsivo. Recomendo que de uma lida na documentação dele e veja se pode lhe ser útil. Mas acima de  tudo recomendo que aprenda sobre os fundamentos de css.

Link do bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/